# Spherical Panoramas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, panoramas

I have created a Spherical Panoramas in Photoshop that I can drag around and see a complete 360 view but I must be in Photoshop. How do I take that and transfer it to the web so a user can click and drag around the view using javascript?  (I do have access to Flash Professional CS 5.5 but I have no experience using it if that program would be better for this application) Also please note I cannot use server side scripts. Please Client Side Scripts Only

***EDIT*** - If there is a free program or javascript based version that is what I am looking for. I would prefer to stay away from paid programs and free programs that watermark the image. I do not mind a simple credit below the main image.

Comment: Are you able to export the image(s) at all?

Comment: [Q&A is hard, let's go shopping!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a couple solutions:

I have Photoshop and I discovered that with Zoomify it will do what I am looking for and it is built right into Photoshop.

Also I saw [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js) that works with ,  and WebGL.

Answer (score 3):

This was my problem few days ago but not anymore now. You have many ways to present it on web page, via plugins(Flash, QTVR, even Java applet) or non-plugin - HTML5.

I personally recommend HTML5, because it's obviously the future of web. When it comes to HTML5, you still have many choices:

1. Three.js

   - Cubic map panorama I: Client browser needs to support WebGL (it means iPhone cannot view this page), and you need to slice the panorama into 6 cube faces. More info [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/canvas_geometry_panorama.html)
   - Cubic map panorama II: Client browser dont need to support WebGL (iPhone can view), every rotate/transform via CSS3d, you still need to slice the panorama into 6 cube faces. More info [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/css3d_panorama.html).
   - Equirectangular panorama: Client browser needs to support WebGL. All you need is an equirectangular image. More info [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_panorama_equirectangular.html).
2. pano2VR.js

   - This is part of the commercial software "pano2vr". This software could slice your equirectangular image into 6 cube face images and present it in a html page, everything automatically. Don't need WebGL, iPhone can view it. More info [here](http://gardengnomesoftware.com/pano2vr.php).

There're far more choices in HTML5 way which I don't remember. Anyway, hope this is helpful for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you've already stitched/assembled your images, you might check out the [krpano Panoramic Viewer](http://krpano.com/). It's a Flash application which displays panoramas. It's also available in Javascript. You can see it in action at [360Cities](http://www.360cities.net).

Comment: I can export the images as one large panorama but I want the animation. I will check that panoramic viewer, thanks

Comment: Sorry, your question did not mention any animation.

Comment: I am only looking for the user to be able to take the 360 panorama and scroll it around to see my view from the camera.

Comment: krpano looks like it will do what you want, then.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it will work but I am looking for a free program (or the javascript to do it) and that one is not free.